# How to stop matlab figure pop up

Tags: matlab, popup, matlab-figure

```
for m=1:10;
    pause(0.2)
    h1=figure(1);
    set(h1,'Position',[200 200 600 500]);
    pause(0.2)
    h2=figure(2);
    set(h2,'Position',[600 200 600 500]);
end
```

When I run upper code, Two figures pop up alternating with each other like below.

[image]

[image]

I would like to stop this pop up property and keep the position during whole iteration like below.

[image]

How could I change this property?

Thank you in advance.

I add a code. in this code, two figures are continuously blinking.
What I want to do is stopping this blinking.

```
clear all
close all
clc
%%patch1%%
x1=[-2 0 0 -2];
y1=[-1 -1 1 1];
z1=[0 0 0 0];
a=patch(x1,y1,z1,'green');
c=patch(x1,y1,z1,'green');

%%patch2%%
x2=[0 2 2 0];
y2=[-1 -1 1 1];
z2=[0 0 0 0];
b=patch(x2,y2,z2,'red');
d=patch(x2,y2,z2,'red');

%h1=figure(1),grid on

    for k=0:pi/10:10*pi
        delete([a b])
        figure(1),grid on
        a=patch(x1,y1,z1+[-0.1*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k)],'green');
        b=patch(x2,y2,z2+[0.3*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k)],'red');
        axis([-2.5 2.5 -1.5 1.5 -0.5 0.5])

        pause(0.05)
        delete([c d])
        figure(2),grid on
        c=patch(x1,y1,z1+[-0.3*sin(k) 0.05*sin(k) -0.05*sin(k) -0.4*sin(k)],'green');
        d=patch(x2,y2,z2+[0.05*sin(k) 0.4*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) -0.05*sin(k)],'red');
        axis([-2.5 2.5 -1.5 1.5 -0.5 0.5])

        pause(0.05)

    end
```

Comment: Have you considered using 1 figure window with 2 plots using [`subplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html?refresh=true)?

Comment: Now, I am using subplot. But, I want to plot two moving graphs on different figures. If there are no ways, I will keep going on using subplot.

Comment: You can [control the location and size of the figure windows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#zmw57dd0e229553) to just make them not overlap...

Comment: Right. But, my concern was blinking of figure.

Comment: If they don't overlap, it won't matter which has focus.

Comment: You should avoid calling `figure` in a loop! It's the lines `h1=figure(1);` and `h2=figure(2);` that keeps switching the focus. And the lines seems unnecessary to call, at least beyond the first call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [''Parent'' property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#zmw57dd0e542603) of the [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) object to specify the [axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) to plot on without needing the [`figure`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) call to update the [current axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html#btxcsre-2).

Using your example:

```
f(1) = figure;
f(2) = figure;
ax(1) = axes('Parent', f(1));
ax(2) = axes('Parent', f(2));

for ii = 1:length(ax)
    axis(ax(ii), [-2.5 2.5 -1.5 1.5 -0.5 0.5]);
    grid(ax(ii), 'on');
    hold(ax(ii), 'on');
end

%%patch1%%
x1=[-2 0 0 -2];
y1=[-1 -1 1 1];
z1=[0 0 0 0];
a=patch(x1,y1,z1,'green', 'Parent', ax(1));
c=patch(x1,y1,z1,'green', 'Parent', ax(2));

%%patch2%%
x2=[0 2 2 0];
y2=[-1 -1 1 1];
z2=[0 0 0 0];
b=patch(x2,y2,z2,'red', 'Parent', ax(1));
d=patch(x2,y2,z2,'red', 'Parent', ax(2));

for k=0:pi/10:10*pi
    delete([a b])
    a=patch(x1,y1,z1+[-0.1*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k)],'green', 'Parent', ax(1));
    b=patch(x2,y2,z2+[0.3*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k)],'red', 'Parent', ax(1));

    pause(0.05)
    delete([c d])
    c=patch(x1,y1,z1+[-0.3*sin(k) 0.05*sin(k) -0.05*sin(k) -0.4*sin(k)],'green', 'Parent', ax(2));
    d=patch(x2,y2,z2+[0.05*sin(k) 0.4*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) -0.05*sin(k)],'red', 'Parent', ax(2));
    pause(0.05)
end

for ii = 1:length(ax)
    hold(ax(ii), 'off');
end
```

As an aside, you can also update your patches by modifying the [`'XData'`, `'YData'`, and `'ZData'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#zmw57dd0e541628) of the patch objects rather than deleting & creating patch objects with every loop. This is generally more efficient.

Using your primary `for` loop as an example ([assumes R2014b or newer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html)):

```
for k=0:pi/10:10*pi
    a.ZData = z1+[-0.1*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k)];
    b.ZData = z2+[0.3*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k)];
    pause(0.05)

    c.ZData = z1+[-0.3*sin(k) 0.05*sin(k) -0.05*sin(k) -0.4*sin(k)];
    d.ZData = z2+[0.05*sin(k) 0.4*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) -0.05*sin(k)];
    pause(0.05)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid calling figure in a loop! It's the lines `h1=figure(1);` and `h2=figure(2);` that keeps switching the focus. Whenever you want to put something in the figure window, use the `'parent',h1` option pair or `'parent',ax1` for some axes object `ax1`. to avoid calling `figure`. I suggest that you only use `figure` to create the figure-window.

For example instead of using `figure(1);image(img);` start by creating the figure and axes objects (`h1=figure(1);ax1=axes('Parent',h1);`), and then whenever you want to update the image in the figure, use `image(img,'Parent',ax1);`.

Comment: I added a code. I am using patch in the figures, when I use 'parent' for patch, matlab say it's not possible.

Comment: According to http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html you can see the the parent property of a patch object should be of type axes, so you can add `,'parent',ax1` (where you of course already have defined your axes object `ax1`) in the end of your call of the `patch`-function.

Comment: I figured out your answer. Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding and removing each patch in each iteration, consider first creating them outside the loop, and then to just change them inside the loop:

```
%%patch1%%
x1=[-2 0 0 -2];
y1=[-1 -1 1 1];
z1=[0 0 0 0];

%%patch2%%
x2=[0 2 2 0];
y2=[-1 -1 1 1];
z2=[0 0 0 0];

figure(1),grid on
a=patch(x1,y1,z1,'green');
b=patch(x2,y2,z2,'red');
axis([-2.5 2.5 -1.5 1.5 -0.5 0.5])

figure(2),grid on
c=patch(x1,y1,z1,'green');
d=patch(x2,y2,z2,'red');
axis([-2.5 2.5 -1.5 1.5 -0.5 0.5])

for k=0:pi/10:10*pi
    set(a, 'ZData', z1+[-0.1*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k)]);
    set(b, 'ZData',z2+[0.3*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k) -0.1*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k)]);

    pause(0.05)
    set(c, 'ZData', z1+[-0.3*sin(k) 0.05*sin(k) -0.05*sin(k) -0.4*sin(k)]);
    set(d, 'ZData', z2+[0.05*sin(k) 0.4*sin(k) 0.3*sin(k) -0.05*sin(k)]);

    pause(0.05)
end
```